# How does a closure save time?

Tags: javascript

When making a a variable local to a function, every time the function is called the array is  reallocated and 10 things are stuffed into it. In a more complicated situation this can take up time.

This closure apparently solves that problem by returning a function. The function it returns is assigned to `digit name` and the function is invoked immediately. I cannot wrap my mind around this. Now I somewhat understand what a closure is, but I have no idea how it is working.

```
var digit_names = (function() {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

    return function (n) {
      return names[n];
  };
}());

alert(digit_names(3)); // 'three'
```

Please explain in detail what is going on here. How is the returned function being invoked before the array is allocated? When I call the function, how is it ignoring `var names` before it gets to the returned function? Or is that question even accurate?

Comment: `alert(digit_names(3)); // actually 'one'`

Comment: it does allocate the array before returning the function

Comment: @guest That's a confusing proposition (which is incorrect in one case) as there are two functions involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by going over what your code does, then further explain what makes it a closure.

```
var digit_names = (function() {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

    return function (n) {
      return names[n];
  };
}());

alert(digit_names(3)); // 'three'
```

To begin with, you have an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (iife):

```
var digit_names = (function () {...}());
```

What this does is it defines a function, and then immediately executes (or, invokes) it. In your case, the function is:

```
function() {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

    return function (n) {
        return names[n];
    };
}
```

What this function does is it first defines a `names` variable that contains an array, then it returns an anonymous function that will return a single element from that array when executed.

Now lets go back to your original code.

```
var digit_names = (function() {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

    return function (n) {
      return names[n];
  };
}());

alert(digit_names(3)); // 'three'
```

`digit_names` is defined as containing the return value of the iife. that means, `digit_names` contains this function:

```
function (n) {
    return names[n];
}
```

Since that function was defined inside the iife, it has access to all variables defined within the iife, making `names` defined as the array. The fact that the function references the `names` array is what makes it a closure.

`digit_names` contains the return value of the iife which is a function that returns a value from the names array. By referencing the names array, that function can be called a *closure*. Put another way, `digit_names` references a function that references a variable that was defined within the same scope that the function was defined in.

---

Here's another example:

```
var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var digit_names = function (n) {
    return names[n];
}
alert(digit_names(3)); // 'three'
```

In this case, `digit_names` still stores a reference to the anonymous function, and the anonymous function is still a closure, however the names array is no longer private. The end result is the same though, because `names` is only created once.

Comment: Thank you so much. What I didn't understand was IIF. I was looking at this as a regular function being called, but this is actually a function stored in a variable. What I'm still not understanding (if you can please include it) is what is the additional `()` for at the end of the IIF, `}());`

Comment: without the `()`, it would just be an FE (function expression). By adding `()` at the end, it gets immediately executed (or "invoked") making it an IIFE. So, instead of storing that function in `digit_names`, you're storing the returned value of it, in this case, an anonymous function that references `names`

Comment: note that nothing is truly *private* in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The closure is *capturing* a reference to the local array `names` **once** and keeps it in scope. The local array `names` is created **only and exactly** at the point when the outer (anonymous) function is called, not when the returned function is called.

Whenever the returned function is invoked, this same local array is accessed, so there is no re-creation of the array. Thus, this would have similar performance behavior to caching the array and reusing it, instead of re-allocating it every time a function is called.

Note that the returned function is not invoked *inside* the outer function. It is only defined there.

**Update**: It appears that the OP is confused about *which function* the name `digit_names` refers to. The name `digit_names` refers to the function which is returned by the outer function, *not the outer function itself*.

The outer function, which was never given a name, is creating the array `names` when it is invoked. The outer function then *gives birth to* the inner function, which captures a reference to `names`. The outer function then *returns* the inner function, which gets the assigned to the variable `digit_names`.

Thus, when that inner (returned) function is invoked as in `digit_names(3)`, it is directly accessing a member of the array that was created by the outer function, which never had a name.

Note that **nothing** is created when `digit_names` is **called**. All the creation happens in the anonymous function that gave birth to `digit_names`.

Comment: If the inside function is only defined in there... when the alert calls the function it sees the variable and allocates it (I WOULD THINK)... how is the inner function being called without first creating the array??

Comment: @MichaelRadar Array is created when outer function is called. The reference inside the inner function keeps it in scope.

Comment: Okay, so when I call the function, `digit_names`, the array is being created and then the value gets returned with the inner function that returns it. I get that. I think. But when you call the function again, how is the function not looking at the variable again and re-creating it before it returns the function??

Comment: @MichaelRader, I understand your source of confusion now.

Comment: @MichaelRader, The function `digit_names` is *not* a reference to the outer function. It is a reference to the *inner* function, which the outer, anonymous function *returns*.

Comment: @MichaelRader, I just updated the answer. If you prefer an answer with more code, take a look at KevinB's answer.

Comment: `digit_names` is not a reference to what outer function? I mean the alert is referencing the `digit_names` function by calling it. I'm sorry but I'm still not understanding. Maybe there's some underlying information I'm getting wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRader, Observe that the `function` keyword is used **twice** in your example. The first time it is used, the *outer function* is defined. The second time it is used, the *inner function* is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, you have an immediately invoked function that creates the {{names}} array once and then returns another function that references the array.  The closure *closes around* the names array and ensures that the array never gets garbage collected as long as there is a reference to the function that contains it.

Your example is semantically equivalent to:

```
function closure() {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'zero', 'one', 'zero', 'one', 'zero', 'one', 'zero', 'one'];

    return function (n) {
      return names[n];
  };
}

var digit_names = closure();
```

{{closure}} is only invoked once and the function that is returned is assigned to {{digit_names}}.  {{digit_names}} contains a reference to the {{names}} variable from {{closure}}.

Because you only need to create {{names}} once, you save allocation time.

Comment: I don't understand how the 'names' variable is closed with a closure? It looks the same to me as any of other function.

Comment: But you do understand the concept, right? are we just dealing with a  terminology issue now? a closure is a function, but not all functions are closures. the `closure` function in andrew's example is not a closure, the function that it returns is a closure. The function that it returns references, or, *wraps*, the names array such that it will stay in scope for that function to reference regardless of where the function is executed. As long as a reference to that function is stored somewhere, the names array will exist for it to access.

Comment: @KevinB no this isn't about terminology. I'm just not understanding still! You say that as long as their is a reference to that function then the array will exist. By calling the function (without returning it from within the function) it is still being referenced, no??

Answer (score 0):

Think of the closure as an amoeba. It takes locally defined variables like 'names' and gelatinously *closes* in around them. It then takes a reference to the 'names' array wherever it goes, and it does not to redefine it every time it gets called.